# Inconsistent results with Android Selenium

Tags: android, selenium, webdriver

I'm getting started with writing tests in Selenium for Android.
I'm trying to run the sample tests on https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver

It might finish successfully 1 in 10 times... But usually the browser opens and something starts happening but I usually get an error.

The most common error I get is:
`org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser.`

I've tried upping the Device Ram size to 1024, 2048, 4096... didn't seem to help much.
I've also tried running it on my android device (Samsung Galaxy S3) and it seems to work more consistently but still not 100% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried Port forwarding like ADB forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080, as this exception comes when  your android server apk not able to communicate with your system.